# Kendo for Jquery static drop down showing up as "undefined" in grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an existing grid creating in Kendo UI for Jquery. I want to put a static drop down/select box in the first field/cell of the grid on each row. When I do it shows up as "undefined".

Most of the examples I see on her and the Telerik site use an editor. In my case the drop down is static. Once they click on an item they will be redirect to another page to do something. At the moment I just want to get the drop down to show up with hard coded options.

```
jQuery(function($){
    "use strict";

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid(){

    ....

columns: [{
   field: "my_links",
   title: "My Links",
   template: "#=getMyLinks(DATA.user_id)#"
},{

   ....

}_.data("kendoGrid");

function setGridData(){

    ....
 });

grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

}

```
setGridData();
```

});

function getMyLinks(user_id){

```
  $('<input id="my_links" name="my_links/>')
      .kendoDropDownList{[
           dataSource: [
               { id: 1, name: "View" },
               { id: 2, name: "Create },
               { id: 3, name: "Delete"}
            ],
          dataTextField: "name",
          dataValueField: "id"
         });
```

}

I would expect a drop down in the

Answer (score 0):

You should provide DOM element for drop down widget in `columns.template` field and then initialize all widgets in `dataBound` event.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
       field: "my_links",
       title: "My Links",
       template: "<input id="my_links" name="my_links/>"
    }],

    dataBound: function (){
        getMyLinks(DATA.user_id);
    }

}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: Thanks. No longer getting "undefined" but just getting blank text field/box.

Comment: I even changed getMyLinks() so that instead of  $('<input id="my_links" name="my_links/>') I have $("#mylinks"). But still just a textfield input box

Comment: @STP You can't select multiple elements by id. You should use another selector. Just define new class $('input.your-class')